# How to Provide SP certificate and metadata

Tags: saml, okta, idp

Maybe that's a wired question.

I want to send AuthNRequest to idp with certifecate and ipd will deny all unauthenticated requests.

My sp metadata configured with a pair of public and secret keys.

IDP metadata configured with the sp public key.

And I've created two AuthNRequests:

first with a public key and the second without.

But for both, I'm receiving the same result (connection established)

I would like that IDP will deny all requests, coming from sp, without recognizing the authentication of the sp.

Is there any way to do that?

I'm using pingone and okta IDPipds.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, IDP needs to authenticate AuthNRequests . Therefore SP need to provide the public key to IDP